# Doubly transitive action on upper half plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry

Can I transform the triangle in the right hand side to a triangle in the left hand side  by a Mobius transform?

[image]

If  $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ acts doubly transitive on $\mathbb{R} \cup \infty$, then do we transform right triangle to left triangle?

I know that $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ triple transitively on boundary of the upper half plane, which is  $\Bbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$. But is it true that $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ acts doubly transitive on $\mathbb{R} \cup \infty$?

Comment: Every triply transitive group action is also doubly transitive: if you are given $(p,q), (p',q')  \in \mathbb R \cup \infty$, first choose an arbitrary $r \in \mathbb R \cup \infty$, then apply triple transitivity to choose $\phi \in PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ such that $\phi(p,q,r)=(p',q',r)$, and it follows that $\phi(p,q)=(p',q')$.